# Reading the next line from a text file

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on an RPG type game for a project and I am stuck.

Basically, this code searches for a name in a text file (structure: odds as names and evens as levels).  It then needs to output the next line which is the level they where on.  I have the counter (variable "count") to output the right text line in which the level is written but I can not use that count to read that line (using "FileSystem.LineInput(count)").

Here is my full code:

```
 Sub LoadGame()
    Dim filename, filepath, searchitem, question, read As String
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim count As Integer = 1
    filename = "save.txt"
    filepath = CurDir() & "\" & filename
    searchitem = name
    FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Input)
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        read = LineInput(1)
        If read = searchitem Then
            found = True
            Exit Do
        Else
            found = False
        End If
        count = count + 1
    Loop
    If found = True Then
        If count >= 3 Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
        question = FileSystem.LineInput(count) ' This bit is broken
        Console.WriteLine("Found save game... Loading: " & question)
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
        Console.Clear()
        Race(question)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("No save game...")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End If
    FileClose(1)
End Sub
```

I am not sure what is wrong but any help would be greatly appreciated (using VB 2010)

Comment: This is why a `Database` is much easier for storing data. Could you show an example of the text format?

Comment: The format of the document is: <name> <level> on different lines

Comment: You're not using LineInput correctly, check the spec http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.lineinput(v=vs.110).aspx .I suggest you don't use legacy functions (CurDir, FileOpen, LineInput). Check out System.IO.File, you can open up a StreamReader and read line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LineInput reads the next line of the specified file (parameter `FileNumber`).

Your file has the `FileNumber` 1 and the file pointer points to the desired line. Therefore, it should be sufficient to

```
question = FileSystem.LineInput(1)
```

In my oppinion, you should avoid those kinds of file access (per FileNumber) in .Net. This is just an old relict from VB6 times. In .Net you have easy-to-use classes such as StreamReader for that purpose. But if you want to do it the old-fashioned way, at least use the `FreeFile` method to define the file number.